# Monic and epic implies isomorphism in an abelian category?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Is it true that monic and epic implies isomorphism in an abelian category?

Comment: Not true generally, for instance, in the category of commutative rings, the inclusion of the integer in the rational is such one, but not iso.

Comment: Wait, is the inclusion $\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow\Bbb Q$ epic?

Comment: Split monic and epic implies iso; as does split epic and monic. But monic and epic does not always imply iso. The counterexample is the monoid of natural numbers, since every number considered as a morphism is both monic and epic, but there's only one number, 0, with an inverse.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to see this, since the rational is generated by the integers.

Comment: Well, there we go. I learned something new.

Comment: OK, that's it, thank you!

Comment: @CameronBuie You can see that the inclusion $\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow \mathbb Q$ is epic in a further way: For every ring $R$ there is at most one morphism $\varphi:\mathbb Q \to R$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is yes, as a consequence of two facts. First, in any category (abelian or not), if the equalizer of a pair of maps is epic, then it is an isomorphism. (Proof: By definition of epic, the two maps that it equalizes must be equal, and then an isomorphism clearly serves as the equalizer.) Second, in an abelian category, every monomorphism is the kernel of some map (this is axiom A3 in the definition of abelian category, on page 35 of Freyd's book "Abelian Categories), which means it's the equalizer of that map and a zero map.

Comment: There is, of course, a dual proof of the same result. Every epimorphism in an abelian category is a cokernel, hence a coequalizer, and (in any category) a monic coequalizer is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do this in light of your answer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - I am not following a step in this argument. In a general category, I am with you on this much: if there exists an epic equalizer for two maps, they are equal. But how do you know that it is an isomorphism? In particular, where/how are you deducing the existence of some inverse?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Once you know that the two maps $A\to B$ are equal, you also  know that the identity morphism of $A$ is an equalizer of them. Now use the fact that any two equalizers of the same pair of maps are isomorphic, via an isomorphism that commutes with the two equalizers' maps to $A$.