# $0 \to A \to B\to C$ is left exact if and only if $f= \ker (g)$.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

We work in an abelian category.

Consider the sequence
$$0 \to A \stackrel{f}\to B \stackrel{g}\to C $$
where $gf=0$. I want to show that if this sequence is left exact, then $f$ is a kernel of $g$.

**My definition of exactness:**

A sequence $A \stackrel{f}\to B \stackrel{g}\to C$ is called exact in $B$ if $H_B=0$, where $H_B= \text{coker}(f')$ where $f'$ is the unique morphism $f': A \to \text{Ker}(g)$ satisfying $\ker(g)f' = f$.

**My attempt:**

I managed to show that $f'$ is an epimorphism. I tried to directly verify the universal property of the kernel, but given a morphism $T \to B$, I don't see how to construct a morphism $A \to T$.

Comment: According to the definitions that I am used to, $\ker g$ would be an object rather than a morphism in the category, which means that "$f$ is the kernel of $g$" doesn't make sense. If a kernel is not an object according to your definition, could you state what your definition is? If a kernel is an object, then can you say what you mean by "$f$ is the kernel of $g$"?

Comment: I've just noticed that you differentiate between a capital-k and lowercase-k kernel. I would guess that you define $\ker(g)$ to be a morphism from $\operatorname{Ker}(g)$ to $B$, is that correct?

Comment: @BenGrossmann A kernel of a morphism $f: A \to B$ is a pair $(K, k: K \to A)$ where $K$ is an object (which is probably what you would call the object kernel) and $k: K \to A$ is a morphism satisfying $fk = 0$ and the usual universal property where all morphisms factor through $K$.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying that

Comment: @BenGrossmann Exactly correct. I write $\text{Ker}(g)$ as the object $K$ in my definition above, and $\ker(g): \text{Ker}(g) \to A$ as the associated morphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can show that $f'$ is a monomorphism, then from your observation $f'$ is both a monomorphism and an epimorphism, [which means](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548641/81360) that $f'$ is an isomorphism. From there, the uniqueness of the kernel up to isomorphism is enough to tell us that $\ker g \circ f' = f$ is a kernel of $g$.

To that end, show that $f$ is a monomorphism using the exactness of $0 \to A \overset{f}{\to}B$. From there, it follows that for any morphisms $\alpha,\beta$ to $A$,
$$
f' \alpha = f' \beta \implies \ker (g)f'\alpha = \ker(g)f'\beta  \implies f\alpha = f \beta \implies \alpha = \beta.
$$

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem completely!