# Category of Abelian group pairs is not Abelian

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, additive-categories

Consider the category of pairs $(X,Y)$ where $X,Y$ are Abelian groups such that $X\subseteq Y$. I want to show that this category is not Abelian. I have checked that this category is additive, and certainly admits kernels and cokernels, so the problem has to be in the last condition, i.e. there is $\mathbf{coim}(f)\not\cong \mathbf{im}(f)$ for some morphism $f:(A,B)\to (A',B')$. I think there might be some extreme counter-example that I am missing under my nose, but I just can't find that out. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that there's a simple counterexample.

Consider $f : (0, \mathbb{Z}) \to (\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ which is the identity in the second slot. That is:

[image: the map of interest]

Can you show that this is a mono and an epi, but is *not* an iso? This will contradict the fact that
every abelian category is [balanced](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/balanced+category) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548641/monic-and-epic-implies-isomorphism-in-an-abelian-category), say)

---

I hope this helps ^_^